# Unifying the product of odd powers of function with the product of even powers of the same function in one product.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions, products

Assume that
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
f_n(x)&= \begin{cases} \big(g(x)\big)\cdot \big(g(x)\big)^3\cdot \big(g(x)\big)^5\cdots \big(g(x)\big)^{n-1},& n \ \text{even},\\
\big(g(x)\big)^2\cdot \big(g(x)\big)^4\cdot \big(g(x)\big)^6\cdots \big(g(x)\big)^{n-1},& n \ \text{odd}, \end{cases}\\
&=\begin{cases}\displaystyle\prod^{n-1}_{k\ \ odd} \big(g(x)\big)^{k}  ,& n \ \text{even},\\
\displaystyle\prod^{n-1}_{k\ \ even}\big(g(x)\big)^{k},& n \ \text{odd}, \end{cases}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where $g(x)$ is any polynomial of order $m$(with real coefficient). I beleive that it's possible to unify the two cases($n$ odd and even) in one product like $\prod^{n-1}_{k=1}(\cdots)$ or $\prod^{n-2}_{k=0}(\cdots)$ $\big($or like $\prod^{n/2}_{k=1}(\cdots)$ or $\prod^{(n/2)-1}_{k=0}(\cdots)$$\big)$ which gives the desired $f_n(x)$ for each $n$. I hope someone helps me to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about $g(x)^{\lfloor n^2/4\rfloor}$?

Answer (score 2):

We can actually simplify this considerably. It turns out that if $n$ is even, then
$$1+3+...+n-1=\frac{n^2}{4}\tag{1}$$
and if $n$ is odd, then
$$2+4+...+n-1=\frac{n^2-1}{4}\tag{2}$$
Now, notice that the function
$$\frac{n^2-n}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\bigg\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\bigg\rfloor$$
is equal to $(1)$ for even $n$ and $(2)$ for odd $n$. Thus, we have
$$f_n(x)=g(x)^{\frac{n^2-n}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}$$

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:
$$
\prod_{k=1}^{\lfloor \frac n2 \rfloor} g(x)^{n+1-2k}
$$

Comment: I got formula like this : $\displaystyle\prod^{\lfloor \frac{ n} {2} \rfloor }_{k=1}{{g^{n-(2k-1)}}(x)}$. I hope there exists another formula.

Comment: I don't think we can anything much better if we just want to fiddle with the indexes. But for the specific situation, Rob Pratt's simplification is definitely the way to go!

Answer (score 0):

you can do much better actually. Let me start with $n=2N+1$ odd, then
$$
f_n(x)=g(x)^{\sum_{k=0}^{N}(2k)}=g(x)^{2\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}k}=g(x)^{N(N+1)}
$$
and for $n=2N$ even 
$$
f_n(x)=g(x)^{\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}(2k+1)}=g(x)^{2\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}k+N}=g(x)^{N(N+2)}
$$
There are many ways to rewrite this in a single line, one of them is
$$
f_n=g(x)^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor\left(\lfloor n/2\rfloor+1+\frac{1+(-1)^n}{2}\right)}
$$